# Can I use a variable string to call a method?

Tags: function, variables, methods, jscript, testcomplete

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have 25 queries to run that are in a separate file. They are all named by what they are returning. So if I want to loop through them, can I just use a variable to call each query I want to return?

```
    var _Q = QueryFile;

    var part1 = generalName;  //Amount
    var part2 = aqString.Replace(Object1.wSelectedItems, " ", "");  //Due
    var part3 = aqString.Replace(Object2.wText, " ", "");  //LessThan

    var allParts = part1+part2+part3;  //AmountDueLessThan

    var query = _Q.queryName();  //query = AmountDueLessThan()

    Log.Message(query);
```

part1 never changes, part2 changes every five iterations, and part three changes every iteration. I'm trying to write a function to execute this piece so that it works for all 25 queries.

Is there a way to format the queryName string to call the query from QueryFile?

Thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is QueryFile in your case.

In general, there are two ways to do this in TestComplete using JScript/JavaScript.

1. If the separate files are added to your project as script units, you can use the [Runner.CallMethod](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/project-objects/items/script/runner/callmethod.html) routine:

   ```
   var _Q = "MyFile";
   var fName = "AmountDueLessThan";
   Runner.CallMethod(_Q + "." + fName);
   ```
2. Use the **eval** function.

   ```
   var fName = "AmountDueLessThan";
   eval(fName + "()");
   ```

Comment: The eval function worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dan, great! So, you can accept my answer as a solution. ;)